# How to change the right with the left button?

Tags: winapi, mouse-hook

I'm using the following winapi-code to change the right-button clicks with left-button clicks.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    if (wParam == WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, lParam);
    }
    else if (wParam == WM_RBUTTONUP)
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, WM_LBUTTONUP, lParam);
    }
    else if (wParam == WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK)
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK, lParam);
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
 }
```

The hook works very good, but it seems that this technique is read-only (I read this in some other stackoverflow question). This is what I want to do:

```
Left click -> Press left button.
Right click -> Press left button.
```

Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but that will swap the buttons, I want to just change the right with the left.

Comment: Maybe because of my poor English I'm not understanding. This is what I want to do: `Left click -> Press left button. Right click -> Press left button.`. Using `SystemParametersInfo` will do `Left click -> Press right button. Right click -> Press left button.` right? Or I'm wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion :-). However, I never used the *swap* word, I just said *change the right-button clicks with left-button clicks*. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Also it's difficult to me sometimes to explain my problems in English. Btw, any ideas?

Comment: In English, "change x with y" means "swap x with y". You meant to write "change x to y". Do you want to do this globally or just within your program?

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks for your comment, I didn't know that about the language! Mmm I think for me it's the same, it will be better if I do it within my program but it's the same. Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: If it's just your program, then you can do `if (message == WM_RBUTTONDOWN) message = WM_LBUTTONDOWN` for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I'm doing (see the code above), but it seems that Windows Hooks are read-only. Any other idea?

Comment: Swap them in your window procedure, not in a hook.

Comment: That should work, but I'm using a DLL that is loaded in a 3rd process. Will that work?

Comment: It will work for your DLL's windows.

Comment: My DLL doesn't launch any window. So I think that's not a solution. But really thank you very very much for your help. Any other idea?

Comment: You need the cooperation of the windows to get this to work. For example, if they call `GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)` they need to know to check `GetKeyState(VK_RBUTTON)` too.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand that. How can `GetKeyState` help me here?

Comment: I'm not saying it helps you. I'm saying that it hurts you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SwapMouseButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function easily to swap mouse buttons.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't want to *swap* the buttons, I want to change the right button with the left button.

Comment: I don't see any difference. What do you mean exactly by changing the right/left key?

Comment: See the comments to the original question. I asked @cdonts to edit the question to make it clear, but the request was rejected.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, you can use SwapMouseButton to swap them when user uses your application and swap back when leaving your application.

Comment: It wasn't rejected @KenWhite, it's just that I don't know what to edit! How can I make the question clearer? Mustafa, I'll check out that. Thanks!

Comment: @cdonts: The exact information that I asked you to add, and that I just referred this poster to: [the comment where you made it clear what you were asking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491859/how-to-change-the-right-with-the-left-button/21504048?noredirect=1#comment32442613_21491859).